# about uniqueness of IVP with separable ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

if I have an IVP with a separable ODE, which theorem states uniqueness for it? Please help. I need to prove it without solving.

Answer (score 1):

There ain't no one. The standard example for non-uniqueness of solutions
$$
y'(t)=\sqrt{|y(t)|}
$$
is separable.

However, Cauchy's theorem states that if $f$ in $y'=f(t,y)$ is continuously differentiable (in $y$, continuous in $t$), then every IVP has a unique solution (which may reach infinity before reaching the end of the integration interval, see $y'=y^2$).